# Should the node_modules directory be tracked by a VCS?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I just discovered the power of Grunt and have a very basic question. Grunt creates a directory named `node_modules` as well as the `package.json` and the `Gruntfile.js` files. When I look at [Git repositories of other projects](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compress/blob/master/.gitignore), I see that `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` files have been committed, but the `node_module` directory is not. Why?

What is the best practice concerning the `node_modules` directory and the other two files?

Comment: You mean uploading to production? A part of deployment step should be `npm install --production`. You certainly should avoid manual uploads though, `git pull --ff-only` is a much safer approach.

Answer (score 1):

You must run `npm install` on production and ignore `node_modules` in you repository.

`node_modules` can contain compiled native modules for you platform and server platform can be different, for example.

Comment: Also npm docs: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git